# Cannot delete address value from address array (solidity)

Tags: solidity, arrays

I've run into some odd behavior of solidity. In the following example:

```
// Omit corner cases for brevity
contract C {
    address[] addrList;

    function addAddr(address addr) {
        addrList.push(addr);
    }

    function deleteAddr(address addr) {

        for(uint256 i = 0; i < addrList.length; i++) {
             if(addr == addrList[i]) {
                 for(uint256 j = i; j < addrList.length; j++) {
                     addrList[j] = addrList[j + 1];
                 }
                 delete addrList[addrList.length - 1];
                 addrList.length--; // <== This gives Error: Expression has to be an lvalue.
             }
        }
    }
}
```

it cannot resize the length of the array once the value has been deleted. Why can't the length of the address array be decremented?

Deleting integers from an integer array is [possible](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/how-to-delete-an-element-at-a-certain-index-in-an-array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to execute the code in *browser-solidity* with a private *geth 1.4.10* node and it worked.

Here my receipt:

```
Result: {
  "blockHash": "0x18f6fc3b76958dcbf841bbbc9d9e039a1920fe68679fbc80fa091f4b0174c73b",
  "blockNumber": 1156,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 21464,
  "from": "0x0fd8cd36bebcee2bcb35e24c925af5cf7ea9475d",
  "gasUsed": 21464,
  "logs": [],
  "root": "94baadfff43ba52cac5cf14f6d43e04351207f8bae1f30503aaced9bc4295e8b",
  "to": "0xa5da304da6eac9cc6ce5292385a396ef8ded4e9a",
  "transactionHash": "0x5f27bc3f984609bc69b59f6eee002e66b9ba8fa698e680fda54dbb7fb04c3d6d",
  "transactionIndex": 0
}
Transaction cost: 21464 gas.
```

Comment: I'm missing something (this is a simplified version of the code).

Comment: I've found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839122/in-ethereum-solidity-when-changing-an-array-length-i-get-value-must-be-an-lva Basically you can't resize memory attributes only storage attributes.

Comment: this I knew but your code was not a Memory thing ;-)