# Removing Array Element by Copying to Temp Array

Tags: arrays

I read you can delete an array element like this:
[How to delete an element at a certain index in an array?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/how-to-delete-an-element-at-a-certain-index-in-an-array)

I was wondering if I can do it this way too:

```
  function playerUnjoins() {
    address[] newActivePlayers;
    for (uint32 index; index < activePlayers.length; index++) {
      if(msg.sender == activePlayers[index])
        newActivePlayers.push(activePlayers[index]);
    }
    activePlayers.length = newActivePlayers.length;
    activePlayers = newActivePlayers;
  }
```

This is shorter and looks more readable. `activePlayers` is an array of `address` stored in the blockchain.

## Question

Is it possible? I get this warning:
[image]

When I write it with `address[] memory newActivePlayers;` I get (in https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.2+commit.af6afb04.js):

```
Untitled:94:9: Error: Member "push" is not available in address[] memory outside of storage.
        newActivePlayers.push(activePlayers[index]);
    ^-------------------^
```