# Is removal of elements from arrays possible in solidity?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, contract-design, arrays, ethereumjs

Assume a `struct Node` and an array of Nodes `allNodes[]`. I was successful in adding `Node` to the array but when I tried to use a `removeNode()` method (which uses the `delete` method in arrays), the value of `allNodes.length` remains the same. Is it because blockchains are "immutable". Doesn't immutable mean that when a transaction is made (even `remove Node()`), it cannot be undone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete an element at a certain index in an array?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/how-to-delete-an-element-at-a-certain-index-in-an-array)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I already mentioned that I am using `delete` method. The problem here is if I manually move my `Nodes`, the next time I try adding an element using the `push`method, will there be any conflict...because the last element remains unchanged in the manual method.

Comment: Delete doesn't reorganize the array or change the length as one might expect. Some contract design ideas over here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it doesn't do exactly what you (probably) expect.

It signals "no important data here" and helps keep things efficient at the platform level but it doesn't reorganize the array at the application level, by which I mean it doesn't shift all the elements above the deleted row down one row. Length doesn't change.

Immutability has an impact here. No matter what we do, we are only appending to the previous state. Nothing is truly deleted. Even the transactions that created, updated and ultimately deleted the "row" are part of the immutable history. "Delete" can't be about obliterating data, but it might be about reorganizing it.

Have a look over here: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

"Mapped Structs with Delete-enabled Index" does a logical delete. It's appropriate for situations where a high percentage of rows will be deleted and you want to avoid looping over garbage.

The much simpler "Mapping with Struct" is more common. It sets a "bit" to indicate a logical delete.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you sir....but is it legal to manually increase/decrease the `allNodes.length` variable? Like `allNodes.length ++` or `allNodes.length --` ...

Comment: Yes. Possibly someone will chime in some certainty about all the edge cases around ++. I haven't used it enough to be certain and I don't wish to mislead you. Probably a matter of taste - I like to push() because it leaves no doubt about what exists in the new row.