# How can I exclude msg.sender from a list

Tags: solidity

For the sake of humanity, could anyone help please?

A splitValue is send by msg.sender - the sender is part of the beneficiaryList - but excluded from the list at moment of sending. 
How would that look like in code?

I have a start:

```
uint splitValue = uint(msg.value/beneficiaryList.length);
     for (uint index = 0; index < beneficiaryList.length; index++) { 
     beneficiaryList [index].transfer(SplitValue); 

     if(participants[msg.sender] != 0){
     beneficiaryList [index] != (msg.sender); }
```

Not sure if the last two lines are correct.

Answer (score 2):

If `beneficiaryList` is an array or addresses, and you're looping through the array, you'd simply check it against `msg.sender` and skip it if it matches. So something like:

```
uint splitValue = uint(msg.value/beneficiaryList.length);
uint l = beneficiaryList.length;
for (uint index = 0; index < l; index++) { 
    address b = beneficiaryList[index];
    if (b != msg.sender) {
        b.transfer(splitValue);
    }
}
```

I can't help with the final two lines as I can't tell what they're supposed to do.

BTW, be aware that there are a few code smells in what you're doing that may indicate that you should change your approach. Unless you know that `beneficiaryList` will have a limited length, your code may run out of gas, and you may never be able to run it because it exceeds the block gas limit. Also, since the beneficiary address may be the address of a contract and `transfer` will call the default payment function it, it could throw an exception or cause you to run out of gas, and which will also prevent anybody from using the function. Depending on the other code it may also have reentrancy issues. Consider using the [withdrawal pattern](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#withdrawal-from-contracts) instead.

Comment: Thank you. The last two lines should exclude msg.sender from the array, before calculating. This is an array of all participants. When transfer is done it should be done to all other participants, so everyone except the sender (msg.sender). Not sure how to code this.

Comment: See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/how-to-delete-an-element-at-a-certain-index-in-an-array or one of the related questions. You already looped through the array so you could have kept the index. Depending what you're doing an array may not be ideal, eg a linked list may be better.