# Efficient approach to delete element from array in Solidity

Tags: solidity, gas, arrays, mapping, struct

For each user, I want to keep an array of holded assets (each asset has an ID).

My solution up until now is :

```
struct User {
        uint userId;
        uint[] assets;
    }
```

For every `asset` the user holds I push to the user's array the `ID` of the `asset`.

I want to give the user an option to delete an `asset`.

What would be the most efficient approach to this?

Allocating all of the available `assets` for every user (would be very wasterful given you have a lot of assets available) VS. iterating over all of his `assets` everytime he'd like to delete an `asset`, finding it in the array, then deleting it from it and shifting all of the array accordingly - also, the code for this is kinda hideous :

```
function deleteAsset(uint assetId) external returns(uint) {
        bool assetFound = false;
        // Check if the asset found is the last asset (or we go out of boundaries)
        if (allUsers[msg.sender].assets[allUsers[msg.sender].assets.length - 1] == assetId){
            assetFound = true;
        }

        else{
            // Iterate over all user assets and find its index
            for (uint i = 0; i < allUsers[msg.sender].assets.length - 1; i++) {
                if (!assetFound && allUsers[msg.sender].assets[i] == assetId)
                    assetFound = true;

                if(assetFound)
                    allUsers[msg.sender].assets[i] = allUsers[msg.sender].assets[i + 1];
            }
        }

        if (assetFound){
            delete allUsers[msg.sender].assets[allUsers[msg.sender].assets.length - 1];
            allUsers[msg.sender].assets.length--;
        }
    }
```

Would be a lot easier if I could save a `mapping` for each user indicating what asset does he have, but you can't return a `mapping` from a function and I don't know the benchmarks of `view` functions and "brute-forcing" all of the assets available for each user can take a plenty of time I assume.

Comment: Heres a method to delete an array element at a given index
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/how-to-delete-an-element-at-a-certain-index-in-an-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete an element at a certain index in an array?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/how-to-delete-an-element-at-a-certain-index-in-an-array)

Comment: I'm aware of these threads, I also presented their method. Though my situation is a bit different and I'm asking about efficiency.

Comment: The title should be something like: Efficient approach to delete element in Solidity dynamically sized array

Comment: @RomanFrolov True, edited.

Answer (score 13):

Source: https://github.com/su-squares/ethereum-contract/blob/master/contracts/SuNFT.sol

Here you go:

Algorithm:

```
uint[] assets;
mapping(uint=>uint) indexOfAsset;

function removeAssetFromArray(uint _assetToDelete) {
  uint index = indexOfAsset[_assetToDelete];
  if (!index) return;

  if (assets.length > 1) {
    assets[index] = assets[assets.length-1];
  }
  assets.length--; // Implicitly recovers gas from last element storage
}
```

Caveat: this approach assumes an ordered set, not an array. In other words, it assumes the array has no duplicate items.

Comment: @random Does this help?

Comment: No it just refunds gas setting non-zero storage values to zero again. 
It's a little cheaper than explicity saynig delete array[index] 

That being said no answers on efficiency in this thread so guess I'll have to research myself.

Comment: This is unbelievable simple solution for my use case.. thanks..

Comment: Do you also need to remove the entry from indexOfAsset?

Comment: How does it work for the first element ?

Comment: Removing from `indexOfAsset` depends on your use case. For my use case (NFTs that are never destroyed), a `removeAssetFromArray` is always followed by a `addAssetToArray` and so there is no need to remove from `indexOfAsset`.

Comment: Removing the first element is the same as removing any asset: the first element is overwritten by the last element and then the last element is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, by moving the last item in the list into the row to delete.

Working from the User `struct` in the OP's code.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract DeleteUser {

    struct UserStruct {
        uint userId;
        uint[] assets;
    }

    mapping(address => UserStruct) public userStructs;

    function deleteUserAsset(address user, uint assetIndex, uint asset) public {
        UserStruct storage u = userStructs[user];
        require(u.assets.length > assetIndex);
        require(u.assets[assetIndex] == asset); // this is a sanity check in case the list was re-ordered
        u.assets[assetIndex] = u.assets[u.assets.length-1];
        u.assets.length--;
    }

}
```

The sanity check isn't strictly needed as the question is worded, but the function relies on the caller knowing what row to delete. This could be a real problem if the list is reorganized by the `deleteUserAsset()` function is called. A simple fix is to add that check, to be on the safe side.

Even better, *in my opinion*, is to not rely on the caller knowing this. In order to do so, we would need a one-step lookup to find the row a particular key lives on. It will take another 32-byte word to store that.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract DeleteUser {

    struct UserStruct {
        bytes32[] assets;
        mapping(bytes32 => uint) assetPointers;
    }

    mapping(address => UserStruct) userStructs;

    function isUserAsset(address user, bytes32 assetId) public view returns(bool isIndeed) {
        if(userStructs[user].assets.length == 0) return false;
        return userStructs[user].assets[userStructs[user].assetPointers[assetId]] == assetId;
    }

    function deleteUserAsset(address user, bytes32 assetId) public {
        UserStruct storage u = userStructs[user];
        require(isUserAsset(user, assetId));
        uint rowToDelete = u.assetPointers[assetId];
        u.assets[rowToDelete] = u.assets[u.assets.length-1];
        u.assets.length--;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For starters , I couldn't create a storage array with more than 100 items in a constructor. Likewise I assume having to loop over one will fail too when it grows too large.

**The results are clear, moving indices after deleting an element from a dynamic array is a horrible idea and 0 values should be filtered on the client instead.**

Looping through a storage array with 10 entries and deleting the LAST item

```
 transaction cost   20514 gas
```

Looping through a storage array with 100 entries and deleting the LAST item

```
 transaction cost   43349 gas
```

Looping through a storage array with 10 entries and deleting the MIDDLE item

```
transaction cost    44762 gas
```

Looping through a storage array with 100 entries and deleting the MIDDLE item

```
transaction cost    340387 gas
```

That gas cost increase is just not justifyable.

Comment: Here is how to create a storage array with many elements: `pragma solidity ^0.5.1; contract S {uint[] a;constructor() public {a.length = 2**20;}}`

Comment: Looping is almost always wrong. Based on your other note maybe you have a different use case, perhaps you can open a separate question.