# How to reset the length of array in solidity v6.0?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.6.x

The code gives the following error in solidity v0.6 compiler but works fine with compiler v0.5:

TypeError: Member "length" is read-only and cannot be used to resize arrays.
nodes.length = 0;

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

contract TestNode { 
    uint[] nodes;

    function createNode(uint data) public {
        nodes.length = 0; // This line gives the ERROR
        nodes.push(data);
    }

    function pushNode(uint data) public {
        nodes.push(data);
    }

    function getNode() public view returns(uint[] memory) {
        return nodes;
    }
}
```

How to convert the code that works with solidity v0.6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that'll do it.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.1;

contract TestNode { 
    uint[] nodes;

    function createNode(uint data) public {
        delete nodes; // This should reset the length to zero
        nodes.push(data);
    }

    function pushNode(uint data) public {
        nodes.push(data);
    }

    function getNode() public view returns(uint[] memory) {
        return nodes;
    }
}
```

If you only wanted to remove the last element, then you would `array.pop()`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Since v0.6.0 you can not resize `array.length`.
Member-access to length of arrays is now always read-only, even for storage arrays. It is no longer possible to resize storage arrays by assigning a new value to their length.

Use `push()`, `push(value)` or `pop()` instead, or assign a full array, which will of course overwrite the existing content. The reason behind this is to prevent storage collisions of gigantic storage arrays.