# Solidity array address delete remains Zero address

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, solidity-0.6.x

i have an array  address[] allAssets which holds list of addresses and it is populated with

```
[
        '0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab',
        '0xaD6D458402F60fD3Bd25163575031ACDce07538D',
        '0x3D0Fc2b7A17d61915bcCA984B9eAA087C5486d18',
        '0xDb28dc14E5Eb60559844F6f900d23Dce35FcaE33',
    ];
```

when i tried to delete first two address from list which gives the following
removed list

```
[
  '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0x3D0Fc2b7A17d61915bcCA984B9eAA087C5486d18',
  '0xDb28dc14E5Eb60559844F6f900d23Dce35FcaE33'
]
```

but i need it to be like

```
[
     
      '0x3D0Fc2b7A17d61915bcCA984B9eAA087C5486d18',
      '0xDb28dc14E5Eb60559844F6f900d23Dce35FcaE33'
    ]
```

Here is my code:

```
 mapping(address => bool) approvedDenominationAssets;
    address[] allAssets;


 function getIndex(address denomination) internal returns (uint256) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < allAssets.length; i++) {
            if (denomination == allAssets[i]) return i;
        }
    }

 function removeAssets(address[] memory _assets) external {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _assets.length; i++) {
            require(
                approvedDenominationAssets[_assets[i]] == true,
                "Asset doesn't exist"
            );
            delete approvedDenominationAssets[_assets[i]];
            delete allAssets[getIndex(_assets[i])];
            emit AssetsDeleted(_assets[i]);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer should help you : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1528/84305

Comment: @hroussille wow it worked.Thanks