# How to pop() a mapping of array in solidity 0.8?

Tags: solidity

The pop() functions works correctly for normal arrays and mappings.

Based on: [How to delete an element at a certain index in an array?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/how-to-delete-an-element-at-a-certain-index-in-an-array)

When I try to pop() an array of a mapping not work.

Any alternative to remove the gaps?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// SPDX-License-Identifier:  
  
contract test {
 
    mapping (address => uint[]) MyMap;

    constructor(){
        MyMap[msg.sender].push(0);
        MyMap[msg.sender].push(1);
        MyMap[msg.sender].push(2);
        MyMap[msg.sender].push(3);
    }

    //Set last into [2] //1
    MyMap[msg.sender][2] = MyMap[msg.sender][MyMap[msg.sender].length - 1];
    //Delete last array position
    MyMap[msg.sender].pop(); //This line is the problem...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by **leonardoalt** in Solidity github:

*"Popping an array of mappings is not allowed because you don't know which keys are dirty or not, so the deleting of the mapping does not actually happen.
If you have an array of mappings, write to it, delete the array, and read the mapping again, the information is still there.
Please see [https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/security-considerations.html#clearing-mappings."](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/security-considerations.html#clearing-mappings.%22)*

Source:
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/13021#issuecomment-1126682792

Answer (score 1):

It always helps to show the full code and error. I'm not entirely sure what `OwnerIndexes` is, because it's not defined in the example. This line `MyMap[msg.sender][2] = MyMap[msg.sender][MyMap.length - 1];` should however also be invalid, since `MyMap` is a mapping and does not have a `.length` attribute. You probably are looking for `MyMap[msg.sender].length`.

Comment: OwnerIndexes is MyMap (I forgot change it)
I am going to try with your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: You are right with the .lenght of array. That fixed that line. Now the problem is when calling the .pop() function--> MyMap[msg.sender].pop();  Any idea? Thanks

Comment: well.. is this exactly the code that you are executing? The constructor part is only added at the end of a contract's deploy code. meaning the pop() would be called before the push. You cannot pop() an array if it is empty. Although then the line before would also be incorrect. Can you show the full code and error message?